# Ejabber Error: module not found when sending a Jingle "session-initiate" stanza

Tags: webrtc, ejabberd, stanza.io

I'm trying to implement a basic audio/video-chat functionality through WebRTC by means of **ejabberd** in JavaScript. To do it, I'm using the Stanza library which implements the following protocols:

[XEP-0166: Jingle](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0166.html)

[XEP-0176: Jingle ICE-UDP Transport Method](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0176.html)

And from the docs I know that Ejabberd supports Jingle ICE ([XEP-0176](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0176.html)). https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#stun-and-turn

When I try sending a Jingle "session-initiate" stanza, as described in XEP-0166, it throws the following error:

```
<error code='503' type='cancel'>
    <service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
    <text xml:lang='en' xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'>No module is handling this query</text>
</error>
```

*What version of ejabberd are you using?*

18.1

*What operating system (version) are you using?*

Centos 7

*How did you install ejabberd (source, package, distribution)?*

Source

If needed, I can post here my installation steps and a config.

Please, advise on how to proceed further with my implementation?

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to send the session-initate to a bare jid (user@host) instead of a full jid (user@host/resource)? The former will be handled by the server and it is quite unlikely that it supports accepting calls that way...

Comment: I'm trying to implement a basic Jingle Interop like here https://github.com/legastero/jingle-interop-demos/tree/gh-pages/stanzaio